# Echo $address variable into google map url parameter

Tags: php, mysql, maps

Hello I am trying to echo out a variable $address into a google map url as such:

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=<?php echo $address; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```

I can't get the variable to echo out in the `<?php echo $address; ?>`

Here is my pagination script, (depricated) I know.

This is the same script that I want the address to be echoed out into the url, so everytime someone searches if an address is brought up then it automatically generates a Static Map.

```
<?php 



 // Connects to your Database 

 mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
error_reporting(0);

 //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 

 if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 



 //Here we count the number of results 

 //Edit $data to be your query 

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bus WHERE fname 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($name)      . "%' AND Address
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($address)       . "%' City
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($city)      . "%' AND state
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($state)         . "%' AND zip
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($zip)   . "%' AND phone
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($phone)     . "%' AND hours
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($hours)     . "%'") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 



 //This is the number of results displayed per page 

 $page_rows = 10; 



 //This tells us the page number of our last page 

 $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 



 //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 

if ($pagenum > $last) {
    $pagenum = $last;
}
if ($pagenum < 1) {
    $pagenum = 1;
}



 //This sets the range to display in our query 

$max = 'limit ' .((($pagenum == 0) ? 1 : $pagenum) - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 

 //This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it

 $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bus WHERE fname 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($name)      . "%' AND Address
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($address)       . "%' City
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($city)      . "%' AND state
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($state)         . "%' AND zip
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($zip)   . "%' AND phone
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($phone)     . "%' AND hours
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($hours)     . "%' $max") or die(mysql_error()); 


 //This is where you display your query results

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) 
{
 echo "<hr width=500><table  width=500><td id=table1><br>Business Name:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $info['fname'];
 echo "<br>Address:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $info['Address']; 
 echo "<br>City:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $info['City']; 
 echo "<br>State:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $info['state']; 
 echo "<br>Zip Code:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $info['zip']; 
 echo "<br>Phone:&nbsp;"; 
  echo $info['phone']; 
 echo "<br>Hours:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $info['hours']; 
 echo "<br></td></table><hr width=500>";
}


 // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages

 echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";


 // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

 if ($pagenum == 1) 

 {

 } 

 else 

 {

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";

 echo " ";

 $previous = $pagenum-1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";

 } 


 //just a spacer

 echo " ---- ";


 //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

 if ($pagenum == $last) 

 {

 } 

 else {

 $next = $pagenum+1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

 echo " ";

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last -></a> ";

 } 

 ?> 
 <?php

 ?>
 <?php
  //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data_p); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 
 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:
        </b> " .$fname; 


 ?>
```

Comment: Use `rawurlencode` to properly encode your query string parameter. And you need to escape `%` and `_` with a `LIKE` search using `addcslashes`. And to prevent XSS, use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting user content to a web page.

Comment: Where do all those variables like `city`, `state`, ect come from?

Comment: It goes into a form to search for them, so like $address would go into <input type=text name=address>

Answer (score 0):

From php 4.0 you need to divine fields from a post with `$_POST['field_name']`. So you need to change it to `$_POST['address']`.

Answer (score -1):

As the address for Google Maps can be anything from full address(zip,house number, street,area,town,region,state,country etc) to any combination of these your approach is wrong.

You should decide what elements you want and have a separate input for each of them. You can then build up the search address from these